# Wrong colour for nodes when creating network diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, nodes, networkx, diagram

When creating a network diagram, some of the nodes are displayed with the wrong colours of the categories.

I wrote the following code that creates a network diagram. It reads data  from two CSV files - one for the adjacency matrix and the other for categories. It supposes to colour the nodes based on the category they belong to, but it ends up colouring some of the nodes wrong. I thought at first that the problem resulted from using shell layout, but it happens also when I do it with different layouts. Assuming nothing is wrong with the csv files (the categories are properly defined, no mismatch between the matrix and the categories etc), what could be the problem?

```
import pandas as pd 
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
def create_network_diagram_from_csv(adjacency_csv_path, categories_csv_path):
     # Read data from CSV into pandas DataFrames
     df_adjacency = pd.read_csv(adjacency_csv_path, index_col=0)
     df_categories = pd.read_csv(categories_csv_path, index_col=0)
 
     # Convert DataFrames to NumPy arrays for easier handling
     adjacency_matrix = df_adjacency.to_numpy()
 
     # Get the node names from the DataFrame's index
     nodes = df_adjacency.index.to_list()
 
     # Create a directed graph using networkx
     G = nx.DiGraph()
 
     # Iterate through the adjacency matrix and add edges to the graph
     for i, source_node in enumerate(nodes):
         for j, target_node in enumerate(nodes):
             edge_weight = adjacency_matrix[i, j]
             if not pd.isna(edge_weight) and edge_weight > 0:
                 G.add_edge(source_node, target_node)
 
     # Create the network diagram using shell layout
     pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
 
     # Get categories for each node from the categories DataFrame
     categories = df_categories.to_dict()['Category']
 
     # Define a mapping of categories to colors
     category_colors = {
         'category_a': 'green',
         'category_b': 'blue',
         'category_c': 'yellow',
         'category_d': 'brown',
         'category_e': 'red',
     }
 
     # Get the colors for each node based on its category
     node_colors = [category_colors.get(categories[node], 'gray') for node in nodes]

     # Customize node size
     node_size = 300
 
     # Draw the network diagram with nodes colored based on categories
     nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=node_size, node_color=node_colors, font_size=10, arrows=True)
 
      #Create a custom legend for categories and colors
     legend_elements = [plt.Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label=category, markerfacecolor=color, markersize=10) for category, color in category_colors.items()]
 
     # Add the legend to the plot
     plt.legend(handles=legend_elements, title='Categories', loc='upper right', frameon=True)
 
     edge_color = 'grey'  # Specify the color of the arrows
     # Draw the edges with the specified edge color
     nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=True, edge_color=edge_color)
 
     plt.show()
 
adjacency_csv_path = r'C:\location of file'
categories_csv_path = r'C:\location of file'
create_network_diagram_from_csv(adjacency_csv_path, categories_csv_path)
```

Catagory data:

```
Node, Category
node_1, category_a
node_2, category_b
node_3, category_d
node_4, category_a
node_5, category_a
```

Adjacency data:

```
 ,node_1,node_2,node_3,node_4,node_5
node_1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
node_2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
node_3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
node_4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0
node_5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your input CSV files.

Comment: An image is **not** reproducible, please provide **text** (and both inputs)

Answer (score 0):

The way you were creating the graph was incorrect, don't loop manually, rather use [`from_pandas_adjacency`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_adjacency.html):

```
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df_adjacency, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

Output:

[image]